# how to fix eslint distructuring state assignment in react?

Tags: reactjs, state, eslint, destructuring

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const { data, image0, image1, image2, image3, image4 } = this.props;
  this.state = {
    data : data,
    image0: image0,
    image1: image1,
    image2: image2,
    image3: image3,
    image4: image4,
  };
}

renderList = () => {
  const { data } = this.state;
  const List = data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Card 
        key={index}
        data={item}
        preview={this.state[`image${index}`]}
      />
    );
  })
}
...
```

Here is a part of my component code. 
We adopt Eslint just now. 
this code throw error 'Must use destructuring state assignment(react/distructuring-assignment)'.
How to fix them???
Our team did not want to turn off this eslint rule(react/distructuring-assignment) for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not a good idea to initialise your state with props. In fact it is a React anti-patterns. You can use the react life-cycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` to achieve this.

Now to answer your actual question, you might want to save an array of images like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {images: []}
}

// props.images contains this array ["image0", "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"]

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if (nextProps.images !== this.props.images) {
     this.setState({ images: nextProps.images })
  }
}

render(){
  const { data } = this.state;
  const List = data.map((item, index) => {

    const { images } = this.state; // destruct images property from this.state

    return (
      <Card 
        key={index}
        data={item}
        preview={images[index]}
      />
    );
  })
}
```